# Loading a corrupted SVN dump file

Tags: svn

Long story short, I had a 4.3 GB SVN dump file, and because of broken DVD sectors, now I have a 4 GB file and a 300 MB file.

`svnadmin load` has no problem with the first chunk, but I'm unable to recover the second one. I can't load it on top of the partially recovered one or in a new one, because there are paths created in the corrupted chunk in the middle that are now lost.

Is there any way to force `svnadmin` to ignore these files, so that at least I can recover whatever files were added in the last 300 MB dump?

Answer (score 1):

There are good chances the 2 files have been splitted raw.

Any luck just "combining" back the two files ?

```
svnRepo=/home/svn
svnDump=/tmp/fullSVN.dump

cat svnDump.dump.part4GB svnDump.dump.part300MB > $svnDump

rm -rf $svnRepo
svnadmin create $svnRepo
svnadmin load $svnRepo < $svnDump
```

Answer (score 0):

Search for a backup which contains those missing revisions `svnadmin load` errors-out on. If you have those revisions then you can repair the repository combining revision history using `svnadmin dump` and `svnadmin load`.

Otherwise, you can forget about the other 300mb dump unless you are willing to do a surgery on the dump file with a text editor.